# How to create AD Object "RID Set" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a question. In AD structure I find AD object `RID Set` which placed as child of `ADComputer` object.

If I create new `ADComputer` object, how can I create `RID set` object in Powershell? Is it possible?

Comment: No, you can't manually do that, the DC's maintain them automatically. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok. I try to recover ADComputer object from AD backup. I create ADComputer and DSRF-Settings as child. But, in backup ADComputer has RID-Set object and I cannot create it. If RID-Set is system object? How AD add it to new ADComputer? Need to restart or another way?

Comment: If it has RID-Set and DFSR-Settings child objects then it's a Domain Controller - do _not_ attempt to restore it by restoring the ADComputer object (you will _royally_ screw up your forest, worst case). Please consult Microsoft's documentation and guides on AD disaster recovery instead

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible?

## No

The `RID-Set` class is marked `System-Only`, meaning that only a DSA (iow. the DC itself) can create such an object.

You can verify this by looking at the schema with `Get-ADObject`:

```
Get-ADObject "CN=RID-Set,$((Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext)" -Properties systemOnly
```

You'll find that the `systemOnly` attribute is set to `$true`